# Return User Role Display Name in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am currently using this snippet to display a users role...

```
<?php 
    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
    $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);
    echo $user_role; // return translate_user_role( $user_role );
?>
```

This works great but it returns the roles slug, how can I modify this so that it returns the roles Display Name instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
global $wp_roles;

$user_roles = $current_user->roles;
$user_role = array_shift($user_roles);

// echo translate_user_role( $wp_roles->roles[ $user_role ]['name'] ); // If you're using multiple languages
echo $wp_roles->roles[ $user_role ]['name'];
```

Un-tested but that should work.

Answer (score 0):

This works for the first item in the roles array for current user:

```
global $wp_roles;   
$wp_roles->roles[ wp_get_current_user()->roles[0] ]['name'];
```