# Get user role name on wordpress with short code

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I am trying to populate the Current logged in user role name but it is showing slug of current user

I want to generate the user role name but not slug

```
function get_user_role() {
    global $current_user;
    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
    $user_role_name = array_shift($user_roles);
    return $user_role_name;
}
add_shortcode('display_user_role', 'get_user_role');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return User Role Display Name in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27948124/return-user-role-display-name-in-wordpress)

Comment: I have already tried all of these but not worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the global [roles API](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_roles/) to get the name of a role.

Something like this:

```php
function get_user_role() {
    global $wp_roles;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    
    if($user){
        if ( !empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
            foreach ( $user->roles as $role )
                echo $wp_roles->roles[$role]['name'];
        }
    }
}
add_shortcode('display_user_role', 'get_user_role');
```